# Send query to json from php

Tags: php, json, curl, httprequest

I am trying to send a url from a php page to a json page in the format

"http://myserver.com/login?q={"myid":"phill","password":"mypass"}"

. If I paste this into a browser address it works correctly. I have tried HttpRequest and cURL with no success. Can you suggest how this may be achieved?.

```
<?php
$yourJSONEncodedData = array('userid' => "phill", 'password' => "mypassword");
$url = "http://myserver.com/login?q=".json_encode($yourJSONEncodedData);
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($output);
$response =  json_decode($output,true);
echo $response;
?>
```

I am expecting "{}" to be returned to the php program.

Comment: Show your code and we'll see what happening, without it, we cannot do too much

Answer (score 2):

I don't know why you are sending parameter in json format? You can send parameters in query string and get all the values in json page.

Comment: Do you mean I should use HttpRequest?. I am new to json and am not sure how to get the values in json page.

Answer (score 1):

Make use of **`json_encode()`** in PHP.

```
<?php
$arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

> The above example will output: {"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}

**Posting the JSON data using cURL** (Something like this)

```
$url="http://myserver.com/login?q=".$yourJSONEncodedData;
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-type: application/json"));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
$output = curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
var_dump($output);
```

That's all i can suggest without seeing your code.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is what I have been trying, but I still get the same response. string(307) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate Set-Cookie: session=52371dfc03643ec12bcf53ad;Path=/ Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8 Content-Encoding: gzip Transfer-Encoding: chunked Server: Jetty(8.1.10.v20130312) ‹«®C¿¦£". I was expecting "{}" to be returned.